# Programming a Grove 5-way switch using ESP-wroom-32 in VSC in C language. Getting 2 errors

Tags: c

The project itself is that the 5-way switch lights up LEDs (each position lights up a different LED).

I can build the project, but after building I keep getting these 2 errors in the terminal:
E (340) i2c: i2c_param_config(760): i2c clock choice is invalid, please check flag and frequency
E (1350) i2c: i2c_set_pin(941): scl and sda gpio numbers are the same

The code is mix of lines from some online tutorials, chat gpt and personal mistakes.

The electronics should be fine, but I'll take a picture of that and post it if needed.

If you know a forum that would be better for this question then please share.

also, question: Do I need all of these lines for i2c configurations like buffers and such? I copied those.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "driver/i2c.h"

#define I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO GPIO_NUM_22  
#define I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO GPIO_NUM_21    
#define I2C_MASTER_NUM I2C_NUM_0         
#define I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ 100000        
#define I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE 0      
#define I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE 0      
#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR 0x68             

#define RED_LED_PIN GPIO_NUM_2
#define YELLOW_LED_PIN GPIO_NUM_4
#define GREEN_LED_PIN GPIO_NUM_12
#define RED_LED_PIN_2 GPIO_NUM_15
#define YELLOW_LED_PIN_2 GPIO_NUM_13

void i2c_init() {
    i2c_config_t conf;
    conf.mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER;
    conf.sda_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO;
    conf.sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE;
    conf.scl_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO;
    conf.scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE;
    conf.master.clk_speed = I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ;
    i2c_param_config(I2C_MASTER_NUM, &conf);
    i2c_driver_install(I2C_MASTER_NUM, conf.mode, I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE, I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE, 0);
}

esp_err_t i2c_master_write_slave(uint8_t* data_wr, size_t size) {
    i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (I2C_SLAVE_ADDR << 1) | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true);
    i2c_master_write(cmd, data_wr, size, true);
    i2c_master_stop(cmd);
    esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_MASTER_NUM, cmd, 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);
    return ret;
}

void initialize_gpio() {
    gpio_set_direction(RED_LED_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(YELLOW_LED_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(GREEN_LED_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(RED_LED_PIN_2, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(YELLOW_LED_PIN_2, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
}

void switch_task(void *pvParameter) {
    uint8_t data;
    while(1) {
        i2c_master_write_slave(&data, 1);
        switch(data) {
            case 0x01:
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN, 1);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(GREEN_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                break;
            case 0x02:
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN, 1);
                gpio_set_level(GREEN_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                break;
            case 0x03:
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(GREEN_LED_PIN, 1);
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                break;
            case 0x04:
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(GREEN_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN_2, 1);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                break;
            case 0x05:
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(GREEN_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN_2, 1);
                break;
            default:
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(GREEN_LED_PIN, 0);
                gpio_set_level(RED_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                gpio_set_level(YELLOW_LED_PIN_2, 0);
                break;
        }
        vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}

void app_main() {
    i2c_init();
    initialize_gpio();
    xTaskCreate(&switch_task, "switch_task", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE * 3, NULL, 5, NULL);
}
```

For the first error I tried changing the frequency to 100000 hz, 400000 hz and 1000000 hz (as I saw on some tutorial that those are most commonly used, couldn't find anything about this on the ESP 32 sheet)

For the second error, I tried changing the pins, but that was a mistake since 21 and 22 are the pins for SDA and SCL (which I saw later on the pin sheet, whoops). Even after changing them I'd get the same error.

I tried changing all the pins for the LEDs as well, but I doubt the problem lies there.